# Hard drive waking from sleep for no apparent reason

Tags: arch-linux, hard-disk, power-management

I have a SATA docking station <sub>(actually part of my PC case)</sub> and use it frequently. One of my SATA disks is a [WD Caviar SE16 WD2500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHL5Y.jpg), a 250GB 7200 RPM SATA3 hard drive. The docking station is connected to a SATA port marked as *external* in the UEFI.

When I plug it in and get whatever I want, I'll issue `sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdd` on my terminal and it immediately goes to sleep mode.

Only, after a random amount of time (ranging from 2 minutes to a couple of hours), it comes back up.

My other drives don't exhibit this behavior and stay in sleep mode until I try to access files from them again.

I'm positive I'm not accessing the drive, nor is any userspace process in my system.

How do I diagnose this, and more importantly, how do I make sure it *stays* asleep?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there can be uncountable reasons for drives to wake up.

For example, I had this issue with my new WD80EZAZ drives. Turns out a simple `smartctl -a` wakes them up (just query SMART data, not even running any tests). This was not the case with my old WD20EARS drives, you could query them while not spinning just fine. So I had to add `-n standby` to my `smartd.conf` to ignore the drives while in standby (add this either to your `DEVICESCAN` line or to the appropriate device lines).

Other popular reasons are filesystems, for example `ext4` with lazy init might periodically access the drive. You can set `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump` or use other tools to find out, or use `mount -o loop,ro` for a read-only mount to rule out periodic (write) access by the filesystem itself.

If you have an invalid `/etc/fstab` entry, specifying an UUID that does not exist, this can also lead to all drives being scanned for the missing UUID, waking everything up in the process. It's why you sometimes see people use `/dev/disk/by-uuid/the-thing` instead of `UUID=the-thing` as that prevents additional scanning: the by-uuid symlink either exists or it doesn't, unlike `findfs` it does not traverse all drives every single time.

Also check `dmesg` for regular bus resets or other such issues. A wonky cable can also cause odd side effects.

Unfortunately there's no easy answer to this problem and it can be difficult to pinpoint the exact cause.

Comment: thanks for that `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump` tipp, it's a livesaver when debugging hdd wakeups!