# Investigate why my disks are not going to sleep - which files are open?

Tags: linux, nas

I want to investigate what keeps my drives spinning on my nas. Which commands help me to get insight on which files are being opened and preventing my disks to sleep?

Comment: sometimes its enough if smartd is running ... or a new ext4 filesystem is still doing the lazy init ... maybe related https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533796/30851

Comment: `btrace` can be handy: it "traverses" all block layers.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, you should use the `lsof` command:

```
lsof | grep /path/to/your/disk
```

This command will show you which processes have files open on that disk.

Comment: This will not work if you run docker containers. The opened files will not show up

Comment: @faze you didnt ask for Docker... Its better to add Docker to your question.

Comment: Open files do not necessarily mean they are being read from/written to. An application may create and delete files.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo fatrace --timestamp --filter='WD<>+'`